# Use angular js controller to check a cookie and return a modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I am implementing a SPA wherein I have a html element that calls an angularjs controller.

Here is my requirement:

I wish to check in the controller whether there is a specific cookie available:
     - if yes, then call a service
     - if not, then return a modal (with some questions that I wish to store in cookies when the user clicks "save" in modal)

Till now I am able to check the cookie in the controller but I am not able to show a modal to the user.

I have already created a html template (partials/question.html) which is using twitter bootstrap modal, but I am not able to return this modal (html) back to the user.

I tried modal service of angularjs but I hit the bottom of it as I am not able to create the same html template using the same (it works but its not as a cool ui).

Any suggestion or code snippet that I use for reference would be a great help.

Edit missing code :

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                            templateUrl: 'partials/questionaire.tpl.html',
                            controller: 'QuestionaireController',
                            size: 'lg',
                            windowClass: 'modal-fit',
                            resolve: {
                                 questionaires: function () {
                                    return $scope.questionaires;
                                 }
                            }
                        });


'partials/questionaire.tpl.html'            
===     
<div class="modal fade" id="questionaireModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="questionaireModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" ng-controller="QuestionaireController as questionaireCtrl">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        ....
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!
AJ

Comment: include your source code, point to the error. you must have a specific question or you will be downvoted.

Comment: Use jquery from controller: `$('#yourModalName').modal('show');`
Your template must be included (ex. with `<div data-ng-include data-src="'partials/question.html'"></div>`)

From here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing something stupid.

The issue above was that I was creating a modal (using modal-dialog and modal-content class of bootstrap) and then passing the above template to $modal service to return to the view on a condition.

Once I remove the modal-dialog from the template, then it worked like a charm.